# Stat Testing multiple response question

Tags: statistical-significance

I have data from 500 respondents for a question, which of the following brands of phones have you seen/heard advertising in past 3 months?
a) Apple
b) Samsung
c) Nokia
d) Motorola
e) Lenovo
f) Others (Please Specify)

The responses I have are as below:
a) Apple: 90% (450/500)
b) Samsung: 88% (440/500)
c) Nokia: 85% (425/500)
d) Motorola: 20% (100/500)
e) Lenovo: 15% (75/500)
f) Others (Please Specify): 5% (25/500)

Which is the most appropriate stat test to test if there is any significance difference between Apple & Samsung. I thought of Z-Test, but since the populations of ad awareness is not independent, I don't think it can be used. Please advise.

Answer (score 2):

How about turning it into a $2\times2$ contingency table and perfoming a $\chi^2$-squared test?

```
contingency.table <- data.frame(Apple = c(450, 50), Samsung = c(440, 60))
rownames(contingency.table) <- c("yes", "no")
chisq.test(contingency.table)
```

No significant difference is detected between the proportion of people who have seen/heard from Apple or Samsung from advertising in past 3 months:

```
    Pearson's Chi-squared test with Yates' continuity correction

data:  contingency.table
X-squared = 0.82737, df = 1, p-value = 0.363
```

Just a small note on the study design, 3 months is a long period of time and (as expected) just about everybody has heard of both brands in this time period.

Comment: A Fisher exact test can also be used (and would be preferable for a small sample size)

Comment: Although small observed counts generally result in small expected counts, the Fisher exact test is more precise for the latter, not necessarily for a smaller number of observed counts.